# How to convert foreach loop to a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

With the following structure

```
[[1,10],[2,20],[5,45],[10,34]]
```

this foreach loop finds the first element that matches "planYear". If planYear=5 then the third element value of "45" would be selected.

```
List<object> gifts = gifts;
foreach (List<object> item in gifts)
{
  if (item[0] == planYear)
  {
    gift = Convert.ToDouble(item[1]);
    break;
  }
}
```

What would be an analogous Linq statement to achieve this same result?

Comment: Install ReSharper, Alt+Enter on `foreach` :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: You did had the `comment` of the day for daniels answer which you deleted :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes I did, but I don't like being too outwardly sarky or flippant :-)

Comment: The types here are a bit confused...is it `List<List<object>> gifts` or what? Because you can't have `List<object> gifts = gifts;`, or `foreach (List<object> item in gifts)` where `gifts` is a `List<object>`.

Comment: @TimS. Well taking the code above it's a `List<object>`, but the `foreach` can do a cast to `List<object>` again, so it's in effect a `List<List<object>>`. However, LINQ cannot play that trick without `Cast` or `OfType` on the `gifts` enumerable before starting.

Comment: @TimS.: The code of the OP works. The `foreach` automatically performs a cast from `object` to `List<object>` here.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bad example, but it looks like you're reinventing `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Poorly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var gift = Convert.ToDouble(
               gifts.Cast<List<object>>().First(x => x[0] == planYear)[1]);
```

Comment: You need to `.Cast<List<object>>()`, but this is more efficient than Daniel Hilgarth's answer.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Why do you think this one is more efficient? Both answers convert only one object to a double.

Comment: @Daniel Less method calls/iterators

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Yes, that's correct. I doubt it will ever be relevant, though.

Answer (score 8):

```
var gift = gifts.Cast<List<object>>()
                .Where(x => x[0] == planYear)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x[1]))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

If no matching entry has been found `gift` will be `0`. If that's not what you want, use `First()` instead. This will throw an exception if no matching item exists.

This answer assumes - just like your `foreach` loop - that every item inside `gifts` is actually a `List<object>`. If even one item is of a different type, this code will throw an `InvalidCastException`. If this is a problem, use `OfType` instead of `Cast`.